# I can't enable Pipelight?

Tags: kubuntu, pipelight

I've been trying to install pipelight on Kubuntu (I've dual booted into it on my chromebook).
However when I attempt to enable pipelight it doesn't work.

```
(precise)george@localhost:~$ sudo pipelight-plugin --enable silverlight
sudo: pipelight-plugin: command not found
```

Comment: Are you trying to "install" or "run" pipelight?

Comment: I think I have installed it, I'm now trying to enable the plugin, and I keep getting told that the command cannot be found.

Comment: Reinstall pipelight, i think you haven't installed it yet

Answer (score 0):

Reinstall pipelight using the correct repository:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:pipelight/stable 
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends pipelight-multi
```

If none of those commands gave an error, type

```
sudo pipelight-plugin --update
```

Source: [Pipelight.net/Ubuntu](http://pipelight.net/cms/install/installation-ubuntu.html).